# Simple Java English to French Word Translation Using Arrays

Tags: arrays, sequential, linear-search

Hello Stackoverflow Community. I'm currently going through an old CS class learning assignment that I found online. I need to use arrays to convert English words to French and vice versa using 2 string arrays and a linear search. I set up the linear search but I'm having difficulty setting up the process to draw the output from the 2nd array. Below is what I put together so far but as I said, I'm stumped on drawing the output from the input. Any guidance is appreciated!

```
import java.text.*; // general package for formatting
import javax.swing.*; // for GUI
public class Translation
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String[] eng = {"hello", "goodbye", "cat", "dog"};
      String[] fre = {"bonjour", "au revoir", "le chat", "le chien"};
      String word;

      word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter word");
      sequentialSearch(eng, word);  
   }   

   public static int sequentialSearch(new words[], int target)
   {
      int index;
      int element;
      boolean found;
      index = 0;
      element = -1;
      found = false;

      while (!found && index < words.length)
      {
         if (words[index] == target)
         {
            found = true;
            element = index;
         }
         index++
      }
      return element;   
   }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the words are a one-to-one match you simply need to display the word from the `fre` array at the same index as the english word.

In other words, if the search matched the entry at `eng[1]` then you want to display the word at `fre[1]`

Comment: Hi Mark. I assumed that's what I need to do, but I'm not as familiar with that array process. I'm good with pulling from 1 array but not swtiching between the 2.